# A Canvas Constructor Function

Tags: canvas, constructor

What would a canvas constructor function look like? I thought something like this but there's something obviously wrong.

```
function Canvas(canvas) {
    this.canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    this.width = 400;
    this.height = 400;
    this.style.border = "1px solid";
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    this.context = canvas.getContext('2d');
}

var canvas1 = new Canvas('canvas1');
```

Answer (score 0):

Several issues with your code. You are not referencing the correct variables. `this` is an object you have created, not canvas element, so you can't do `this.style.border=` and other similar assignments. Here's a working constructor:

```
function Canvas(canvas) {
    this.canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    this.canvas.width = 400;
    this.canvas.height = 408;
    this.canvas.style.border = "1px solid";
    document.body.appendChild(this.canvas);
    this.canvas.context = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
}
```

Comment: So the canvas property of the object I am creating is the canvas?

Answer (score 0):

You are only referencing the `this` which is the object itself, not the canvas you created. This should work:

```
function Canvas(canvasID) {
    this.canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

    this.canvas.width = 400;
    this.canvas.height = 400;

    this.context = this.canvas.getContext('2d');

    this.canvas.style.border = "1px solid";
    this.canvas.id = canvasID;               // or use name

    document.body.appendChild(this.canvas);
}

var canvas1 = new Canvas('canvas1');
canvas1.context.fillRect(0, 0, 400, 400);
```

When you are inside the function scope the `this` references the object itself. You are setting a new property on the object (canvas etc.) so in order to reference those you need to use the same property name inside the object, ie. `this.canvas` and so on.

There is really not much point setting an id/name though as you already has a reference to the element in the object unless you use CSS or queries.

You could also pass in width and height or use default values if they are not provided:

```
function Canvas(canvasID, width, height) {
    this.canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

    this.canvas.width = width || 400;
    this.canvas.height = height || 400;

    this.context = this.canvas.getContext('2d');

    this.canvas.style.border = "1px solid";
    this.canvas.id = canvasID;               // or use name

    document.body.appendChild(this.canvas);
}

var canvas1 = new Canvas('canvas1');              //  400x400
var canvas2 = new Canvas('bigCanvas', 2000, 500); // 2000x500
```